# What exactly do quotation marks around the table name do?

Tags: sql, oracle

I thought that the quotation mark (") was simply a type of grouping marker but I'm debugging some NHibernate code and notice that while

```
SELECT * FROM site WHERE site_id = 3;
```

Works fine

```
SELECT * FROM "site" WHERE site_id = 3;
```

fails with a table or view does not exist error.

What gives?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Putting double-quotes around an identifier in Oracle causes Oracle to treat the identifier as case sensitive rather than using the default of case-insensitivity.  If you create a table (or a column) with double-quotes around the name, you must always refer to the identifier with double quotes and by correctly specifying the case (with the exception of all upper case identifiers, where double-quotes are meaningless).

Under the covers, Oracle is always doing case-sensitive identifier matching.  But it always casts identifiers that are not double-quoted to upper case before doing the matching.  If you put double-quotes around an identifier, Oracle skips the casting to upper case.

So if you do something like

```
CREATE TABLE my_table( 
  col1 number,
  col2 number
)
```

you can

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
SELECT * FROM My_Table
SELECT * FROM "MY_TABLE"
```

but something like

```
SELECT * FROM "my_table"
```

will fail.

On the other hand, if you do something like

```
CREATE TABLE "my_other_table"( 
  col1 number,
  col2 number
)
```

you cannot do

```
SELECT * FROM my_other_table
SELECT * FROM MY_OTHER_TABLE
SELECT * FROM My_Other_Table
SELECT * FROM "MY_OTHER_TABLE"
```

but this

```
SELECT * FROM "my_other_table"
```

will work

Comment: This answer leaves out the fact that it also allows identifiers to contain characters that would otherwise be illegal, such as a space character. It's also probably best practice to use only upper case letters, digits, and underscore. Doing so will make everyone's lives easier.

Comment: The answer also leaves out the fact that it also allows identifiers to start with a non-alphabetic character (i.e. numeric). The full list can be found in [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49).

Answer (score 12):

It should be added that identifiers in quotation marks may contain special characters, e.g. "a-b c.d" is a valid identifier.