# SQL: how to query a column named "Sysdate"

Tags: sql

I have a column named Sysdate in several tables, which is causing SQL errors when I try to Select it. It works if "Sysdate" is enclosed in double-quotes, e.g.

```
SELECT "Sysdate" FROM table1
```

When I try to use aliases it causes syntax errors:

```
SELECT t1."Sysdate" FROM table1 AS t1
```

Please advise.

Thank you,

Max.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162381/how-do-i-escape-a-reserved-word-in-oracle

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I haven't even finished browsing reddit :)
Thank you guys, I will test it and accept one of the answers.
M.>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what database?   MySQL allows you to escape reserved keywords using backticks:

```
SELECT `sysdate` FROM TABLE1
```

In SQL Server, you use hard brackets:

```
SELECT [sysdate] FROM TABLE1
```

Oracle uses double quotes:

```
SELECT "sysdate" FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for sql server

```
SELECT [Sysdate] FROM table1
```

for MySQl this should work, those are back ticks btw

```
SELECT `Sysdate` FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT [Sysdate] FROM table1;
```