# SQL Query for an update of a column based on other column's data in a Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write an SQL query to take either from one of two column's data(based on whichever is available and not null) and append it to a static text into another column within the same table.

Can anybody tell me how to write this?

Example Data :

```
ID  Type   Barcode  Serial No  Location

1   Test    ABCD     1234       LOC1  
2   Test    EFGH     NULL       LOC2  
3   Test    NULL     5678       LOC3  
4   Test    NULL     NULL       LOC1
```

Final Data Reqd in Format

```
ID  Type  Barcode  Serial No  Location

1   Test  ABCD     1234       LOC1-ABCD   (Append barcode if its not null)  
2   Test  EFGH     NULL       LOC2-EFGH   (Append barcode if its not null)  
3   Test  NULL     5678       LOC3-5678   (Append serial no since barcode is null)  
4   Test  NULL     NULL       LOC1        (Both r Null keep loc as it is)
```

Please help me on it....really stuck on this :(

Database is Oracle 10.

Supra

Update 1 :

Thanks a lot Marco for your help....the location field only needs to updated in the table after appending the barcode/serial no from the same table into location field. Your edited query is not working :(...please let me know if I need to give some more info/data.

Final Update :

Shesek's Answer worked perfect :D...you are the man :)...Thanks a ton :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment on the other answer,

```
UPDATE Network_Plant_Items
    SET FULL_ADDRESS = 'foobar' || COALESCE(BARCODE, MANUF_SERIAL_NUMBER)
    WHERE BARCODE IS NOT NULL OR MANUF_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to append this to the current value of FULL_ADDRESS, as I understand from the original question,

```
UPDATE Network_Plant_Items
    SET FULL_ADDRESS = FULL_ADDRESS || COALESCE(BARCODE, MANUF_SERIAL_NUMBER)
    WHERE BARCODE IS NOT NULL OR MANUF_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
```

`COALESCE()` returns the first non-NULL argument you pass to it. See Oracle's [manual page on it](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions023.htm).

Just as a general FIY, `NVM()` that was suggested by another answers is the old Oracle-specific version of `COALESCE()`, which works kinda the same - but it only supports two arguments and evaluates the second argument even if the first one is non-null (or in other words, its not short-circuit evaluated). Generally, it should be avoided and the standard `COALESCE` should be used instead, unless you explicitly need to evaluate all the arguments even when there's no need for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, Type, Barcode, "Serial No",
CASE
  WHEN Barcode IS NOT NULL THEN Location || '-' || Barcode
  WHEN "Serial No" IS NOT NULL THEN Location || '-' || "Serial No"
  ELSE Location
FROM your_table
```

Take a look at [CASE function](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/case_when.html) and [String Concat](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html).
I'm not sure the way I escaped *Serial No* field, anyway look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162381/how-do-i-escape-a-reserved-word-in-oracle)

**EDITED:**
Try this:

```
UPDATE your_table SET Location =
CASE
  WHEN Barcode IS NOT NULL THEN Location || '-' || Barcode
  WHEN "Serial No" IS NOT NULL THEN Location || '-' || "Serial No"
  ELSE Location
```

Comment: @Supra: please **don't put** large code blocks into comments - they're **extremely hard** to read..... instead: update your original question by **editing it** to provide additional info!

Comment: @Supra: take a look at my edited code. I don't have Oracle, so I cannot test the query...

Comment: Thanks a lot Marco for your help....the location field only needs to updated in the table after appending the barcode/serial no from the same table into location field. Your edited query is not working :(...please let me know if I need to give some more info/data

Comment: Sorry for putting the sql block....newbie to stackoverflow....will try and keep things clear.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have Oracle installed, so can't test query, but this should work....

You could use NVL function, but it's good for 2 options (use value a if it's not null, and if it is, use value b)

```
update myTable
set myCol = NVL(colA,colB)
```

Since you however want to concatenate if and only if you get a non-null value from either column, you need to get a little trickier and combine using nested NVL()

```
update myTable
set myCol = myCol || CASE NVL(NVL(colA,colB),0) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '-' || NVL(colA,colB)
```

Explanation:

- NVL(colA,colB) will evaluate to colA first, colB if colA is null, and null if both are null
- In all situations I return the column's value
- I then append - if both are null, I essentially am appending 2 empty strings ('' and NULL); otherwise, I'm appending '-' and the value I evaluate to
- I use a CASE statement to do an IF .. ELSE to figure if I need '-'
- I use nested NVL functions to assign 0 if both are null to make the CASE logic easy
- I then append my evaluated value

As I said before, this is untested, so there could be some syntax issues, but the logic is correct :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just look for rows where one of them is not null using WHERE?