# "date" as a column name

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, ora-00904, ora-01747

I have a table called calendars.

One of its columns is named 'date'

When I want to select the date column it gives error ORA-01747 namely invalid table.column.

```
select date from calendars
```

I guess this happens because 'date' is a reserved word for pl/sql. The problem is it's not even possible to change the column name :

```
alter table calendars rename column date to date_d
```

Result is:  ORA-00904 error: invalid identifier.

What do you advice?

Thanks.

Comment: paste your 'desc calendars' please

Comment: It *really* should be valid to use (any) reserved word as a column name as `"date"` or `[date]` (but perhaps the latter is TSQL?), but I don't use Oracle so... perhaps the schema is not as expected?

Comment: (BTW, try as I might, I can't even create a table in oracle with a column named date)

Comment: yes but you can --> create table a ("DATE" date), if you want to make the table user suffer :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you tried

```
select calendars.date from calendars; /* or you could alias "calendars" if you don't want to type so much */
```

If that doesn't work or help, have you tried dropping the column (and maybe try referencing it with the table name prefix: `calendars.date`)?

---

I also found this post: [How do I escape a reserved word in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162381/how-do-i-escape-a-reserved-word-in-oracle)

It seems that Oracle will be case-sensitive if you use double quotes so

```
select "date" from calendars;
```

is not the same as

```
select "Date" from calendars;
```

Comment: it gives ORA-01747 error when I add the table name or alias. I didnt try to drop the column but there is no problem with select * from calendars. So I dont need to drop the column if any further action wouldnt be taken.

Comment: select "DATE" from calendars  solved it. It was DATE, not date.

Answer (score 10):

Try escaping the reserved word with double quotes.

```
select "date" from calendars
```

Comment: The double-quotes seem to make Oracle act in a case-sensitive fashion when looking for the `date` column.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner That is true. Case must match exactly when using double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

date is a reserved keyword and hence cannot be used like

SELECT date from some table

there can be multiple solutions for the problem

- The date column needs to be enclosed within the brackets like

> SELECT [date] FROM tableName

- Enclose the reserved keyword in  backticks

> SELECT 'date' from tableName

- Use alias

> SELECT tableName.date from tableName