# Access SQL Delete DateTime not working

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to execute following code for I have hardcoded the date in but it doesn't seem to delete it before I had data mismatch expection.

```
string myQuery = "DELETE FROM Class WHERE Date=#10/12/2015#;";
```

Comment: you must end each statement with a semicolon, the part in the quotes is your string

Comment: no I'm doing this in C# OLE DB

Comment: ANSI SQL-92 and other standards require to terminate SQL statements with semicolon. However, most current RDBS implementations do not require the use of this terminator.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be starting a transaction and not committing or anything along those lines?  The query String looks ok at the surface.  Perhaps some more of the code might shine some light.

Comment: No I'm not, it doesn't throw any exceptions or anything, I really don't know why it's not deleting it

Comment: date could be confused for a Keyword, might need to make an alias to get at it or escape it.  See this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842262/date-as-a-column-name

Comment: Alright, I'll try that Bearcat9425, thanks!

Comment: No problem hope it works.

Comment: To debug things like this: run the SQL string `DELETE FROM Class WHERE Date=#10/12/2015#;` directly in Access as query. (assuming Access is available)

Answer (score 1):

I ran the SQL query in Access and it didn't work. So I generated it using the tools avaliable there and it looks like that:

```
DELETE Class.ClassDate FROM Class WHERE (((Class.ClassDate)=#12/10/2015#));
```

Comment: Then all that was wrong with your original SQL was the column name - `Date` instead of `ClassDate`. And the reason it didn't throw an error is: `Date` is also a function. Had you entered the today date instead of `#10/12/2015#`, it would have deleted all data in your table instead of nothing... You were lucky. :)

Comment: So does this query work for you in your C# application?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
string myQuery = "DELETE FROM Class WHERE Date=#10/12/2015#;";
```

use

```
string myQuery = "DELETE FROM Class WHERE Date=#10/12/2015#";
```

Be sure not to put ; before " in Access SQL in C#

Answer (score 0):

A good reality check is to replace DELETE with SELECT *, if the WHERE clause doesn't return any rows in a SELECT query, it isn't going to delete any either.

Is it possible there is a time component stored in the field Date? The value #10/12/2015# is implicitly #10/12/2015 12:00 AM#, and a test for equality will only return rows that match exactly.  If you're actually looking for all rows with any time of day on that date...

```
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN #10/12/2015# AND #10/12/2015 11:59 PM#
```

(Not sure if Date is a reserved word in Access -- life is too short to depend on Jet -- but even if it isn't the square brackets won't hurt anything.)