# SQL Error: ORA-00942 table or view does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I use SQL developer and i made a connection to my database with the system user, after I created a user and made a another connection with that user with all needed privileges.

But when I try to proceed following I get the SQL Error

> ORA-00942 table or view does not exist.:

---

```
INSERT INTO customer (c_id,name,surname) VALUES ('1','Micheal','Jackson')
```

Answer (score 80):

Because this post is the top one found on stackoverflow when searching for "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist insert", I want to mention another possible cause of this error (at least in Oracle 12c): a table uses a sequence to set a default value and the user executing the insert query does not have select privilege on the sequence. This was my problem and it took me an unnecessarily long time to figure it out.

To reproduce the problem, execute the following SQL as `user1`:

```
create sequence seq_customer_id;

create table customer (
c_id number(10) default seq_customer_id.nextval primary key,
name varchar(100) not null,
surname varchar(100) not null
);

grant select, insert, update, delete on customer to user2;
```

Then, execute this insert statement as `user2`:

```
insert into user1.customer (name,surname) values ('michael','jackson');
```

The result will be "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" even though `user2` does have insert and select privileges on `user1.customer` table and is correctly prefixing the table with the schema owner name. To avoid the problem, you must grant select privilege on the sequence:

```
grant select on seq_customer_id to user2;
```

Comment: Just went through the same scenario. Very irritating that you get 00942 when the actual issue is a sequence permissioning issue.

Comment: You save my life, that works like a charm! Oracle is not explicit with this error.

Answer (score 20):

Either the user doesn't have privileges needed to see the table, the table doesn't exist or you are running the query in the wrong schema

Does the table exist?

```sql
    select owner, 
           object_name 
    from dba_objects 
    where object_name = any ('CUSTOMER','customer');
```

What privileges did you grant?

```sql
    grant select, insert on customer to user;
```

Are you running the query against the owner from the first query?

Comment: `dba_objects` is not accessible for a regular user. You should use `all_objects` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest, Ive executed the first query to see the owner of the 'customer' table, I got the result "0 rows selected". 
so that means the user that I created does not have needed priviliges I guess ?

Answer (score 16):

Case sensitive Tables (table names created with double-quotes) can throw this same error as well. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327223/ora-00904-when-inserting-querying-data-from-tables/13329029#13329029) for more information.

Simply wrap the table in double quotes:

```
INSERT INTO "customer" (c_id,name,surname) VALUES ('1','Micheal','Jackson')
```

Answer (score 11):

You cannot directly access the `table` with the name `customer`. Either it should be `user1.customer` or create a synonym `customer` for user2 pointing to `user1.customer`. hope this helps..

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer: http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/synonyms.htm

An Oracle synonym basically allows you to create a pointer to an object that exists somewhere else. You need Oracle synonyms because when you are logged into Oracle, it looks for all objects you are querying in your schema (account). If they are not there, it will give you an error telling you that they do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Oracle Database and i had same problem. Eventually i found ORACLE DB is converting all the metadata (table/sp/view/trigger) in upper case.

And i was trying how i wrote table name (myTempTable) in sql whereas it expect how it store table name in databsae (MYTEMPTABLE). Also same applicable on column name.

It is quite common problem with developer whoever used sql and now jumped into ORACLE DB.

Answer (score 0):

in my case when i used asp.net core app i had a mistake in my `sql query`. If your `database` contains many `schemas`, you have to write `schema_name` before `table_name`, like:
`Select * from SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME...`
i hope it will helpful.