# SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 00942. 00000 - "table or view does not exist"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pluggable-database

I'm new to the Oracle PL/SQL. So I created a pluggable database named "EGITIM" as seen here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNeOD.png)

Then I got a SQL script from a UDEMY course. These scripts are for creating tables,inserting datas etc. First script is for creating tables. I executed it and created the tables successfully as seen here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1TMc.png)

But when I executed the other script which adds data to these table, i got an error for every table I've created:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Unknown Command: COMMIT
```

The SQL script:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into EGITIM.BOLGELER (BOLGE_KODU,BOLGE_ADI) values ('1','İÇ ANADOLU');
Insert into EGITIM.BOLGELER (BOLGE_KODU,BOLGE_ADI) values ('2','MARMARA');
Insert into EGITIM.BOLGELER (BOLGE_KODU,BOLGE_ADI) values ('3','EGE');
Insert into EGITIM.BOLGELER (BOLGE_KODU,BOLGE_ADI) values ('4','AKDENİZ');
Insert into EGITIM.BOLGELER (BOLGE_KODU,BOLGE_ADI) values ('5','DOĞU ANADALU');
Insert into EGITIM.BOLGELER (BOLGE_KODU,BOLGE_ADI) values ('6','GÜNEY DOĞU ANADOLU');
Insert into EGITIM.BOLGELER (BOLGE_KODU,BOLGE_ADI) values ('7','KARADENİZ');

////// same lines with other tables and datas
//////
//////
//////

COMMIT;
```

I tried to GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to the user I created for this database. But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you successfully created tables in `EGITIM` schema, I guess you're connected as `EGITIM`; aren't you? If not, you should be!

This:

```
Insert into EGITIM.BOLGELER (BOLGE_KODU,BOLGE_ADI) values ('1','İÇ ANADOLU');
```

inserts row into table named `BOLGELER` which is owned by `EGITIM` user. As table owner, you (once again: presuming you're connected as `EGITIM`!) don't have any privileges on your own table - you can insert rows, update values, delete rows ... *everything*.

Apparently, something *is* wrong. As the only table involved in statement I posted is `BOLGELER`, what happens when you run the following:

```
select user from dual;
select owner from all_objects where object_name = 'BOLGELER';
```

Depending on your answer, we'll see what to do next.

Comment: So I haven't created a user named "EGITIM". When i try to, i get some other error that says "ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name". So i thought maybe deleting the database then recreating a pdb and user "EGITIM" is a good idea. But I can't drop database either. I really struggle with Oracle a lot.

Comment: Right; Oracle made things complicated lately, it was simpler up to 11g. Anyway: connect as PDB (pluggable database) SYS user as it lets you create other users. Then create a new user (in PDB, of course), either by manually entering CREATE USER statement, or using GUI (SQL Developer). Here's a tutorial which shows how to create user: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tutorial-create-sql-developer-account/?learningpath=true&appuser=nobody&appsession=4002114003250&contentid=26772&activityname=Create%20a%20SQL%20Developer%20User%20Account&eventid=6310

Comment: Once you're done, connect as newly created EGITIM user and **then** run your scripts (first to create tables, second to insert data).

Comment: I somehow managed to create user "EGITIM" than it all worked out for me. Thanks for interest.

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad you made it work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a permission issue, you're not using the table owner to alter it.

Switching to a connection with those credentials and granting select privileges on the sequence should fix the issue:

```
grant select on seq_customer_id to user2;
```

You can find possible solutions under this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129912/sql-error-ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist?rq=2).