# JDBC - How do I 'getString' from a ResultSet if the column's name is a keyword?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, keyword

Whenever I try to retrieve the value for a column named "Comment" in an Access db (.mdb), It gives me the following error.

```
Offence: copying data
ERROR - Offence TABLE
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "Comment": invalid identifier
```

This is my code:

```
public static void copyOffenceTable()
    {
        PreparedStatement updateOffenceTypeTable  = null;

        //Set up "insert" string
        String insertString = "INSERT INTO Offence "
                + "(id, OffenceName, status, OffenceSuburb, OffenceDate, FirstName, LastName, \"Comment\", OffenderAddress, OffenderSuburb, OffenderPostcode, OffenderState, OffenderEmail, LicenceNumber, DOB, StaffIssuerID, OffenderPhone) "                                          
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        String MSAccessQuery = "SELECT * FROM Offence";

        try
        {
            //create a query object for MSAccess
            dbmsMSAccess.DBMSStatement = dbmsMSAccess.DBMSConnection.createStatement();
            //Query the MSAccess database for extraction
            dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet = dbmsMSAccess.DBMSStatement.executeQuery(MSAccessQuery);
            //make query object for Oracle
            dbmsOracle.DBMSOracleStatement = dbmsOracle.DBMSOracleConnection.createStatement();

            dbmsOracle.DBMSOracleStatement.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE Offence");

            dbmsOracle.DBMSOracleConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

            updateOffenceTypeTable = dbmsOracle.DBMSOracleConnection.prepareStatement(insertString);

            System.out.println("Offence: copying data");

            while(dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.next())
            {
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setInt(1, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getInt("id") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setString(2, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("OffenceName") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setString(3, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("Status") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setString(4, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("OffenceSuburb") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setDate(5, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getDate("OffenceDate") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setString(6, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("FirstName") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setString(7, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("LastName") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setString(8, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("COMMENT") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setString(9, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("OffenderAddress") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setString(10, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("OffenderSuburb") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setInt(11, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getInt("OffenderPostcode") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setString(12, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("OffenderState") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setString(13, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("OffenderEmail") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setInt(14, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getInt("LicenceNumber") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setDate(15, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getDate("DOB") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setInt(16, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getInt("StaffIssuerID") );
                updateOffenceTypeTable.setInt(17, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getInt("OffenderPhone") );

                updateOffenceTypeTable.executeUpdate();
            }

            System.out.println("Offence: ACCESS DATA COPIED TO ORACLE\n");
        }
        catch(Exception X)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR - Offence TABLE");
            X.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Is there a way to refer to a column that is also a keyword through jdbc?

I've tried putting 'comment' between apostrophes and also quote marks.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: The values are being placed into an oracle database with supposedly identical tables.

Comment: if you dont use any quotes '," does it also fails with same error?

Comment: @harsh yup, and also if i add any brackets.

Comment: How are you connecting to Access .mdb and getting ORA error codes?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I forgot to mention that i was putting them into an Oracle database. Sorry about that =[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, None of these methods suggested worked for me, however they were worth a shot!

I ended up having to go into the database and get permission to change the field from comment to comments.

Thanks everyone who posted i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try with some brackets:

```
 String insertString = "INSERT INTO Offence "
                + "(id, OffenceName, status, OffenceSuburb, OffenceDate, FirstName, LastName, [Comment], OffenderAddress, OffenderSuburb, OffenderPostcode, OffenderState, OffenderEmail, LicenceNumber, DOB, StaffIssuerID, OffenderPhone) "                                          
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

EDIT:
For oracle, if we trust this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1162391/291541

The solution is the double quote but you have to pay attention to the case. Please check if your column is comment instead of Comment by example.

Comment: Unfortunately not. =[

It gives me another exception about the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Please remove Double Quotes inside the Query

```
   String insertString = "INSERT INTO Offence "
                + "(id, OffenceName, status, OffenceSuburb, OffenceDate, FirstName, LastName, Comment, OffenderAddress, OffenderSuburb, OffenderPostcode, OffenderState, OffenderEmail, LicenceNumber, DOB, StaffIssuerID, OffenderPhone) "                                          
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: unfortunately it just gave me another exception:

"java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Comment: In the Question you specified the MDB file(Access). but Code looks like you connect to ORACLE Database, So may be the Table or column anme Correct. I couldn't see any OLEDB Statement here

Comment: Yup, I'm retrieving column data from an Access database, and inserting them into an established oracle database. This is just a static method in my main class All the connections happen in the main method, and i have similar methods for other tables.

Comment: Either Table column name or Table not Exist in Oracle Db. by seeing th e Log this what I know

Answer (score 0):

Won't be possible to rename your column at query level? something like 
`select comment as my_comment from blabla`

You could also reach that field using its index

Comment: Do you mean in the actual database itself, add a subquery into the insertString String? (I'm sorry, i'm actually kinda new to jdbc, it's for university)

Answer (score 0):

Use a back quote (or back tick) to escape the offending column's name like `` `\"Comment\"` ``

```
String insertString = "INSERT INTO Offence "
+ "(id, OffenceName, status, OffenceSuburb, OffenceDate, FirstName, LastName, `\"Comment\"`, OffenderAddress, OffenderSuburb, OffenderPostcode, OffenderState, OffenderEmail, LicenceNumber, DOB, StaffIssuerID, OffenderPhone) "                                          
+ "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: nope, it just gives me this error    "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification" =/

Comment: You said your database is .mdb but your error codes suggest it's Oracle (ORA). I just realised but why is so?

Comment: I'm retrieving access columns and inserting them into an Oracle database. Oh god i forgot to mention it. Sorry about that =S.