# How do you escape oracle reserved keywords when using Doctrine DBAL to execute queries on an Oracle database?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, doctrine-orm, dbal

I'm trying to use Doctrine DBAL to execute the following query on an Oracle database. I've executed other queries before so it's not a connection issue. The problem stems from trying to escape the reserved word `Number`. I need to select a column as `Number` for later logic down the road. The simplified working version of the query is as follows:

```
SELECT instructor.SecNum AS "Number"
      FROM (
           SELECT dbA.ID,
                  dbA.ClsNumber as SecNum,
                  dbA.CrsCatlgNbr,
                  ROW_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY dbA.ClsNumber ORDER BY dbA.CrsCatlgNbr) AS rn
           FROM dbA
           WHERE (dbA.SubCd = '5')
           AND (dbA.ID IS NOT NULL)
           ) instructor,
           (
            SELECT dbB.SecNum
            FROM dbB
            WHERE (dbB.SubCd = '5')
           ) student
      WHERE (instructor.rn = 1)
      AND (instructor.SecNum = student.SecNum);
```

The PHP code is as follows

```
// set up connection stuff and relevant variables
$sectionTable = array();
$dss1prdDatabase->executeQuery(
"SELECT instructor.SecNum AS \"Number\"
      FROM (
           SELECT dbA.ID
                 dbA.ClsNumber as SecNum
                 dbA.CrsCatlgNbr
                 ROW_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY dbA.ClsNumber ORDER BY dbA   CrsCatlgNbr) AS rn
           FROM dbA
           WHERE (dbA.SubCd = '5')
           AND (dbA.ID IS NOT NULL)
           ) instructor,
           (
            SELECT dbB.SecNum
            FROM dbB
            WHERE (dbB.SubCd = '5')
           ) student
      WHERE (instructor.rn = 1)
      AND (instructor.SecNum = student.SecNum);", $sectionTable);
```

When I do this I get an `ORA-00911: invalid character` error.

I've also tried preparing the statement first and then binding the escaped column name to the query:

```
// ...
$ESCAPEDNUMBER = '\"Number\"';
$sql = "SELECT instructor.SecNum AS ?
      FROM (
           SELECT dbA.ID
                 dbA.ClsNumber as SecNum
                 dbA.CrsCatlgNbr
                 ROW_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY dbA.ClsNumber ORDER BY dbA   CrsCatlgNbr) AS rn
           FROM dbA
           WHERE (dbA.SubCd = '5')
           AND (dbA.ID IS NOT NULL)
           ) instructor,
           (
            SELECT dbB.SecNum
            FROM dbB
            WHERE (dbB.SubCd = '5')
           ) student
      WHERE (instructor.rn = 1)
      AND (instructor.SecNum = student.SecNum);"
$stmt = $dbalDatabaseConnection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindvalue(1, $ESCAPEDNUMBER);
$stmt->execute($sectionTable);
```

But this gives me a different error: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.`

The `ORA-00923` error is also found when I say `$ESCAPEDNUMBER = addslashes('"Number"');`

I have no idea what the issue is. Any ideas?

Again my question is how to properly escape oracle reserved words in php queries using Doctrine DBAL. I use quotes because in Oracle quotes are required in the query otherwise you'll get a `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" error.`

Relevant documentation on DBAL can be found [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html)
And also

Comment: This is a MySQL thing and I don't know if it translates to Oracle, but did you try adding `\`` around the column name? e.g. `\`dbA.ClsNumber\`` EDIT: Looks like the [Oracle approach would be to use double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162381/how-do-i-escape-a-reserved-word-in-oracle)

Comment: Yeah Oracle uses double quotes which is why I've been escaping the quotes and such.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid SQL - the second select list is missing commas.

Comment: It's valid SQL. The second select list doesn't need commas as I'm not selecting multiple things...

Comment: `...dbA.ID dbA.ClsNumber as SecNum dbA.CrsCatlgNbr...` - there should be commas in there.

Comment: Fixed. They were there in the larger query I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. The issue was the semi-colon at the end of the query. This works fine in the console but apparently gives the `ORA-00911: invalid character` when ran with DBAL. Go figure...

Fixed query:

```
// set up connection stuff and relevant variables
$sectionTable = array();
$dss1prdDatabase->executeQuery(
"SELECT instructor.SecNum AS \"Number\"
      FROM (
           SELECT dbA.ID
                 dbA.ClsNumber as SecNum
                 dbA.CrsCatlgNbr
                 ROW_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY dbA.ClsNumber ORDER BY dbA   CrsCatlgNbr) AS rn
           FROM dbA
           WHERE (dbA.SubCd = '5')
           AND (dbA.ID IS NOT NULL)
           ) instructor,
           (
            SELECT dbB.SecNum
            FROM dbB
            WHERE (dbB.SubCd = '5')
           ) student
      WHERE (instructor.rn = 1)
      AND (instructor.SecNum = student.SecNum)", $sectionTable);
```