# Attempting to create a table with composite keys and date and time data types. Only get errors

Tags: sql, database, oracle

OK so here is the table and data types I am attempting to create in sql developer:

```
 Table_Name interview
 Field_Name e_number, pos_id, date, time, awarded
 Data_Type  varchar2(9), varchar2(15), date, number(9), varchar2(3) 
 Nulls_Allowed  
 Primary_Key    y, y, n, n, n
 Unique         y, y, n, n, n
 Foreign_Key    
 Comments
```

Here is the sql I am trying to use:

```
 CREATE TABLE interview(
 e_number      VARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 pos_id        VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 date          DATE NOT NULL,
 time          NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
 awarded       VARCHAR2(3),
 CONSTRAINT pk_interview PRIMARY KEY (e_number, pos_id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_e_number FOREIGN KEY (e_number) REFERENCES student
    (e_number),
 CONSTRAINT fk_pos_id FOREIGN KEY (pos_id) REFERENCES position
    (pos_id)
```

Can someone to tell me where I have "invalid identifier"? Cause I am completely lost.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the complete error message? Does it include line and column information to direct you to the actual "invalid identifier"?

Comment: Error starting at line : 20 in command -
CREATE TABLE interview(
  e_number      VARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  pos_id        VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  date          DATE NOT NULL,
  time          NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
  awarded       VARCHAR2(3),
  CONSTRAINT pk_interview PRIMARY KEY (e_number, pos_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_e_number FOREIGN KEY (e_number) REFERENCES student
    (e_number),
  CONSTRAINT fk_pos_id FOREIGN KEY (pos_id) REFERENCES position
    (pos_id)
)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Your `CREATE` statement is not 20 lines long, so what is actually on line 20 exactly?

Comment: The create table starts at line 20, before it is only the comments I have to have.

Comment: `date` and `time` are reserved keywords, so try wrapping those column names in double-quotes, eg: `"date" DATE NOT NULL`, `"time" NUMBER(8) NOT NULL`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162381/how-do-i-escape-a-reserved-word-in-oracle

Comment: Now it is telling me:                                                                           "Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: and add a closing right-parenthesis and semicolon to close the create table scope

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE interview(
    e_number   VARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    pos_id     VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "date"     DATE NOT NULL,
    "time"     NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
    awarded    VARCHAR2(3),
    CONSTRAINT pk_interview PRIMARY KEY (e_number, pos_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_e_number FOREIGN KEY (e_number) REFERENCES student (e_number),
    CONSTRAINT fk_pos_id FOREIGN KEY (pos_id) REFERENCES position (pos_id)
);
```

As suggested by @Remy_Lebeau, @CLifford, and @amdixon

`date` and `time` are reserved words ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162381/how-do-i-escape-a-reserved-word-in-oracle)), so enclose them in quotations. Also, add right parentheses and semicolon to close your table declaration.

Comment: I have the right parentheses and semicolon, but I was still getting "missing right parentheses" error. I was able to create the table but considering I was supposed to create the table with all constraints in the sql syntax I will probably get points taken off and I would like to know how to do this for future references and lab deliverable. Since I had the right parentheses why would it give me the error.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this error is not coming from another part of your code? This is [running on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69470).

Comment: Tried adding a second right parentheses to double check and counted all the others, then tested several other combinations with the same error.