# FROM keyword not found where expected error thrown in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting the above error when I try to run the following query.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER By col1) as ROW , dt.* from  view dt
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

output:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 87
```

Comment: c.f. [How do I escape a reserved word in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162381/how-do-i-escape-a-reserved-word-in-oracle)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ROW is a reserved word in Oracle SQL, don't use it as an alias.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while I was using ROWNUM so be careful not to have *ROW* in any form in your QUERY