# Why am I getting ORA-00904: invalid identifier for deterministic function index?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create or replace function idxF(status IN char) return char deterministic is
retVal CHAR(1);
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('P');
  retVal:=CASE status
  when 'P' then 'P'
  when 'H' then 'H'
  else null
  end  ;
  return retVal;
end idxF;
  create index setIndexOnStatus on ORDER(idXF(STATUS));

  SQL Error: ORA-00904: "IDXF": invalid identifier
```

`STATUS` is a `CHAR(1)` column in `ORDER` table.

Why is the compiler saying that IDXF is an invalid identifier?

Comment: Is this your real function? `dbms_output.put_line('P');` will create problems sooner or later.

Comment: Why not simply `CREATE INDEX setIndexOnStatus ON "ORDER" (CASE status WHEN 'P' THEN 'P' WHEN 'H' THEN 'H' ELSE NULL END);` or `CREATE INDEX setIndexOnStatus ON "ORDER" (CASE WHEN status IN ('P', 'H') THEN status ELSE NULL END);`?

Answer (score 1):

[`ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55357) is a reserved word in Oracle (part of ORDER BY clause) so you shouldn't use it as a name for your table.

Technically, you can [escape a reserved word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162381/how-do-i-escape-a-reserved-word-in-oracle) with double quotes:

```
create index setIndexOnStatus on "ORDER"(idXF(STATUS));
```

Probably, this table was created like this in a first place.

This approach is extremely problematic because you'll need to escape every query to this table and it's not always possible, especially with auto-generated queries.

So, don't go this way, rename the table instead.

P.S. I couldn't reproduce `ORA-00904` on this query. Invalid table name leads to `ORA-00903: invalid table name`. Escaped query works fine for me. If you still have `ORA-00904` error then you'll need to build [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your problem (i.e. include `CREATE TABLE` statement and specify the Oracle version).