# Invalid column name - What is wrong?

Tags: python, sql-server, scrapy, pyodbc

My database

```sql
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Database [company]    Script Date: 06/07/2021 17:01:26 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [company]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'company', FILENAME = N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\company.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'company_log', FILENAME = N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\company_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [company].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF ) 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 60 SECONDS 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET QUERY_STORE = OFF
GO

USE [company]
GO

ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = OFF;
GO

ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET MAXDOP = 0;
GO

ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET PARAMETER_SNIFFING = ON;
GO

ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES = OFF;
GO

ALTER DATABASE [company] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USE [company]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[comp]    Script Date: 06/07/2021 17:01:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[comp](
    [mst] [nchar](14) NOT NULL,
    [company_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [created] [datetime] NULL,
    [modified] [datetime] NULL,
    [legal_representative] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_comp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [mst] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My program

```py
import scrapy
import re
import pyodbc


class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://masothue.com/']
    # cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-23PIH3M;DATABASE=company;UID=sa;PWD=123456a@')
    # cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    # cursor.execute("SELECT comp.mst, comp.address, comp.company_name FROM comp")
    # for row in cursor.fetchall():
    #     print
    #     row

    def parse(self, response):
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-23PIH3M;DATABASE=company;UID=sa;PWD=123456a@')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[comp] ([mst] ,[company_name]  ,[address] ,[legal_representative]) VALUES  (\"343\", \"565\", \"343\", \"343\")")
        cnxn.commit()
        for href in response.xpath("//div/h3/a/@href").extract():
            print('https://masothue.com' + href)
            print(re.search(r'(\d{10})', href).group(1))
```

error

```
C:\Users\donhuvy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>scrapy runspider sc.py
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.3.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.2.0, Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021), cryptography 3.4.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 5f64e686c90fdf8a
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-07-06 19:08:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-07-06 19:08:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://masothue.com/> (referer: None)
2021-07-06 19:08:34 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://masothue.com/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\donhuvy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 662, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\donhuvy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 90, in _parse
    return self.parse(response, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\donhuvy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\sc.py", line 19, in parse
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[comp] ([mst] ,[company_name]  ,[address] ,[legal_representative]) VALUES  (\"343\", \"565\", \"343\", \"343\")")
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name '343'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name '565'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name '343'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name '343'. (207)")
2021-07-06 19:08:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-07-06 19:08:34 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 212,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 17472,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.437639,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 6, 12, 8, 34, 415274),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 81335,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/ProgrammingError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 6, 12, 8, 33, 977635)}
2021-07-06 19:08:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

C:\Users\donhuvy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>
```

What is wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: You use double quote in your program on insert: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[comp] ([mst] ,[company_name]  ,[address] ,[legal_representative]) VALUES  (\"343\", \"565\", \"343\", \"343\")")` and that made error. Use apostrophe (single quote) and double quote.

Comment: Don't close this question, because the error message `Invalid column name '343'` did not reflect the problem correctly. `343` is data, not a column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant hint is the error message `Invalid column name '343'`. In

```py
# WRONG, column names instead of string constants
" ...  VALUES  (\"343\", \"565\", \"343\", \"343\")"
```

You are using double quotes to delimit strings. Strings in Oracle SQL must be put in single quotes. Double quotes are used to escape column names and other identifiers.

```py
# CORRECT
" ...  VALUES  ('343', '565', '343', '343')"
```

This will fix the problem if the corresponding columns are of a text type. For columns of a numeric type, don't use quotes. E.g. if the first column `mst` is a NUMBER, write:

```py
" ...  VALUES  (343, '565', '343', '343')"
```

Note that you can use a column name or an expression in the values clause. Just because it appears in a VALUES clause does not mean that it must be a constant or literal. See: [VALUES expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj11277.html)

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1162757/880990
- [Difference between single quote and double quote in Oracle SQL](https://www.dcodeman.com/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-in-oracle-sql/)
- [User-Defined Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#GUID-321084DE-3BDD-484B-AE85-7A991B67C51A) (PL/SQL Language Fundamentals, Oracle help center)

Comment: @DoNhuVy. Sorry to say, but the reported error is correct. In SQL `"343"` is a column name and `'343'` is a string. You wanted it to be data; however, it was not.

Comment: But `"343"` put after `VALUES (` , can you explain for me why `"343"` is still column name? Because this fact cause me cannot diagnostic problem in right way. Can you show me a sample of SQL insert query in case put table name after `VALUES (` words?

Comment: Because you could have a column named `"343"`.