# Unquoted table names don't work

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I've got a question. Why does my Oracle Express Edition requires double-quoted table names:

Not working select:

```
select * from table
```

Working select:

```
select * from "table"
```

Thanks for answers and help with editing my post. I was confused how to name this case.

Comment: I understand English is not your mother tongue but you could put some effort in making the question readable. What's your exact problem? Does `select * from table` work or not?

Comment: Yes select * from table is not working; But select * from "table" is...

Comment: This answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/oracle-what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do

Comment: I've tried to make your question clearer. But next time don't forget to post here the error message.

Comment: @Ollie - Nice catch, the explanation is better than mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It requires double quote names only in case the name you are using is a keyword (**and your example - `table` is in this situation**) or if you want to include special characters or non-alphanumeric characters (e.g. `"Multi word table name"`).

The names enclosed in " are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use doublequotes only:
select * from "table";

it works without quotes only of name was created is in uppercase. By default all unquoted names are stored in uppercase.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE "T1" (x number);

-- That works:
select * from "T1";

-- that works too:
select * from t1;

-- that works too:
select * from T1;
```

TABLE - is a keyword. So you can it use without quotes even if you used name in uppercase in create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "TABLE" (x number);

select * from table;

ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

Comment: I would recommend avoiding the use of keywords for databases, tables and column names and then the problem would not happen :)

Comment: Correct - good recommendation, but it does not contradict to the naming rules if use double quotes.