# How to list all the data in a table in sqlplus in oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

This might be a very basic question but I can't find the correct command for it.

I can list the datafields in a table using the command

```
select * from cat where table_name='mytable';
```

How do I check the data that has been inserted in this table using sqlplus?

Comment: Can you try `select * from mytable`?

Comment: I tried that. But it gives me an error saying that 'invalid table name'. However I can see the table when I execute the query that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Are you putting the table name in quotes when you try to select? Oracle treats table names in quotes as case-sensitive; you might have better luck if you leave out the quotes. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/563126/1303955).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-00904: invalid identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027961/ora-00904-invalid-identifier)

Comment: yes I was using quotes with the table name. Leaving the quotes out allowed me to access the data. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the data from a table by using the simple statement:

```
select * from <table name>;
```

so if you want to get all the data from the table `cat`, try:

```
select * from cat;
```

if you'd like to get all the data from `mytable`, try:

```
select * from mytable;
```

any `where` clause that you define in the statement is used to filter the results that this simple 'select everything from' statement would return.

Answer (score 1):

connect to the desired user in which you want to see tables
SQL QUERY: **select table_name from user_tables;**