# Can only login on Oracle as sysdba

Tags: oracle

I just installed 11g2 on Redhat 5.
I logged in using sqlplus as follows:

```
$sqlplus sys/abcabc as sysdba
```

I created a user as follows:

```
sqlplus> create user "xyz" 
           profile "DEFAULT" 
           identified by "abcabc" 
           default tablespace "MYTAB" 
           temporary tablespace "TEMP" 
           account unlock;

sqlplus> grant dba to "xyz"

sqlplus> commit
```

sqlplus reported user created and dba granted. No errors were repored by sqlplus.

Now when I try to login as follows:

```
$sqlplus xyz/abcabc
```

I get a login prompt again and after 3 retries, I'm kicked out.

BUT, if I login as follows:

```
$sqlplus xyz/abcabc as sysdba
```

I get logged in.

What could be the problem? I've followed the exact same procedure for creating a user many times before and it always worked. What is different this time that I need to login as sysdba?

Thanks

Comment: You might get better results posting this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you want to create a case-sensitive username?  That would be very, **very** unusual.

When you [surround an Oracle identifier with double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/oracle-what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do/563126#563126), you are asking Oracle to treat it as a case-sensitive identifier.  So when you

```
create user "xyz"
```

you're asking for a case-sensitive username.  Lots of tools are not going to have trouble passing in case-sensitive identifiers and you have to worry about getting the double-quotes escaped properly in your shell.

Most likely, you really don't want a case-sensitive identifier.  You simply want to use a standard case-insensitive identifier

```
 create user xyz
     profile "DEFAULT" 
     identified by "abcabc" 
     default tablespace "MYTAB" 
     temporary tablespace "TEMP" 
     account unlock;
```

I would prefer that the double-quotes be removed from the tablespace names and the profile names but that isn't causing your issues.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the double quotes were the culprit. I dropped the user and created again without any quotes and things are normal now. It is strange as this used to work previously with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

> BUT, if I login as follows:
>
> ```
> $sqlplus xyz/abcabc as sysdba
> ```
>
> I get logged in.

You will also be able to login like this:

```
$sqlplus / as sysdba
```

That's because the `/ as sysdba` causes Oracle to rely on the OS authentication.  If your OS user is part of the `dba` group (on Unix) or has Administrator privilege (on Windows) you're in.

But your're in as SYS, regardless of whether you specified a user.  This is dangerous because SYS is the owner of the data dictionary, and so it is quite easy to royally muck up the database if you don't know what you're doing.