# Column Alias cannot access in outer query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, union, alias

```
select k.Val, sum(k.Cnt) "Cnt" from 
(
(select a.Env_Location "Val", count( a.VolumeID ) "Cnt"
    from DTree
    join ZCOP_APLNG_Documents a on
     DTree.DataID = a.DataID and DTree.VersionNum = a.VersionNum
    where
     DTree.OwnerID =  -2111 and
     DTree.SubType not in ( 0, 136 ) and
     a.Env_Location is not NULL
     group by a.Env_Location
     )

union
     (select
     b.Env_Location "Val",  count( b.VolumeID ) "Cnt"
    from DTree
    join ZCOP_APLNG_Corr b on
     DTree.DataID = b.DataID and DTree.VersionNum = b.VersionNum
    where
     DTree.OwnerID = -2111 and
     DTree.SubType not in ( 0, 136 ) and
     b.Env_Location is not NULL
     group by b.Env_Location
     )
 ) k     
    group by k.Val
```

can anybody help me to make this work. Showing error Val or Cnt is invalid identifier. Can't we use some column alias for columns??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [case-sensitive identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/oracle-what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do/563126#563126) (almost always a bad idea), every reference to that identifier would need to be case sensitive.  In your case, `"Val"` and `"Cnt"` are both case-sensitive identifiers so you would need to refer to them using the case-sensitive syntax every time.  Something like

```
SELECT k."Val", sum(k."Cnt") "Cnt" from 
   ...
GROUP BY k."Val"
```

In the vast majority of cases, you really don't want to use case sensitive aliases.  You would generally be much better served with

```
SELECT k.val, sum(k.cnt) cnt from 
(
  SELECT a.env_location val, count( a.volumeID ) cnt
  ...
  UNION 
  SELECT b.env_location val, count( b.volumeID) cnt
  ...
) k
 GROUP BY k.val
```

Comment: Thanks Justin.. I didn't know about the case sensitive identifiers.