# Oracle - Table names and columns - could I change the casing?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

By default - Are all oracle table names and columns stored in uppercase?

Could I change to casing?

Answer (score 2):

In the data dictionary, yes, identifiers are converted to upper case by default.

You can change that behavior by creating [case-sensitive identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/oracle-what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do/563126#563126).  It is generally not a good idea to do so, but you can.  In order to do so, you would need to enclose the table name and column names in double quotes both when you create the object and every time you want to refer to them.  You'll also need to get the casing right because the identifiers will be case-sensitive unlike the normal case-insensitive behavior.

If you

```
CREATE TABLE "foo" (
  "MyMixedCaseColumn" number
);
```

then the table name and column name will be stored in mixed case in the data dictionary.  You'll need to use double-quotes to refer to either identifier in the future.  So

```
SELECT "MyMixedCaseColumn"
  FROM "foo"
```

will work.  However, something like

```
SELECT MyMixedCaseColumn
  FROM foo
```

will not.  Nor will

```
SELECT "MyMixedCaseColumn"
  FROM "Foo"
```

Generally, future developers will be grateful if you don't use case-sensitive identifiers.  It's annoying to have to use double-quotes all over the place and not every tool or library has been tested against systems that use case-sensitive identifiers so it's not uncommon for things to break.

Comment: What about if you use lowercasing, do you have to use quotes ? if you did CREATE TABLE foo (mymixedcasecolumn number); and SELECT mymixedcasecolumn
  FROM foo<-- would this work?

Comment: @001 - If you don't use double-quotes, the identifiers will be stored in the data dictionary in upper case regardless of what casing you use in the DDL statement.  Your identifiers will be case-insensitive so you can refer to them however you want in subsequent DML statements.

Comment: If I understand you corectly, if you used quotes on in the CREATE statement, oracle will store as it is with the casing, if you don't use quotes, oracle will default to storing your table and columns in uppercasing? correct?

Comment: @001 - In the data dictionary, correct.  If you don't use double quotes, you can use whatever casing you want to refer to the identifiers in your DML, the identifiers are case sensitive.  If you use double quotes, the identifier is case sensitive.