# SQLDeveloper Trigger Error report - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I put this code into SQL Developer's Worksheet:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_testDSNa
before INSERT
on testDSNa
referencing new as new
for each ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT S_testDSN.nextval INTO :NEW.SYSID FROM dual;
END;
```

I get this:

> ```
> Error report -
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> ```

Would anyone know why?  This has worked for 3 previous tables until I tried to run the DDL to create a 4th.  Alternatively, is there a better way to set up an autoincrementing PK?

Comment: Did you forget to create the testDSNa table?

Comment: Nope, I have it created, and I can insert and delete from it.  However, running Select * from testDSNa; doesn't work either.  Same error.

Comment: Then the table isn't actually named what you think it is.  Is it possible that you surrounded the table name in double quotes when you created it, turning it into a case sensitive identifier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/oracle-what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do/563126#563126)?  If so, you'd need to surround the table name in double quotes every time you reference it (which is one reason that case sensitive identifiers are frowned upon).

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` script you used?

Comment: Hmmm, so I read something weird on another post here, and I tried just typing "User"."testDSNa" instead of just testDSNa, and suddenly it all works again.  Why does this happen?  (User = name of the database, so I think it might be something with the specification of testDSNa, sorta like Java has java.lang.*blah*)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was lack of schema. Oracle Definition of a schema :

> Collection of database objects, including logical structures such as
>   tables, views, sequences, stored procedures, synonyms, indexes,
>   clusters, and database links. A schema has the name of the user who
>   controls it.

If you want to know the objects accessible without alias. You have to look on [USER_OBJECTS]. Which describes the relational objects **owned** by the current user :

```
SELECT 
 OBJECT_NAME
 , OBJECT_TYPE
 , LAST_DDL_TIME
FROM USER_OBJECTS;
```

If you want to know the objects **accessible** to the current user :

```
SELECT 
    OWNER
    , OBJECT_NAME
    , OBJECT_TYPE
    , LAST_DDL_TIME 
FROM ALL_OBJECTS;
```

In your case to see your objects in the list of available tables you need:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OWNER = 'USER';
```

You can also alter the session to avoid alias :

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = User;
```

For priviliges/ roles views you can look at :

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS;
SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS;
```

The last method but not the most secure to avoid alias. Is to log on with a user that has the same name as the schema.

Hoping that it can help

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue.
Solution: What I observed that my table which I created was surrounded by double quotes, which made it case sensitive.
So for each time I refer to my table, I need to surround it by double quotes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_testDSNa
before INSERT
on "testDSNa"
referencing new as new
for each ROW
BEGIN
SELECT S_testDSN.nextval INTO :NEW.SYSID FROM dual;
END;
```

refer this link: [What exactly do quotation marks around the table name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do/563126#563126)