# ROracle: dbGetQuery works but dbListTables and other functions do not

Tags: r, oracle, r-dbi, roracle

I installed ROracle (following the [directions in the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL)) and successfully connected to our Oracle database.

I can run queries, using `dbGetQuery`, and get results just fine, e.g.:

```
> dbGetQuery(con, "select count(*) from table_name")
  COUNT(*)
1     6111
```

However, some of the other DBI/ROracle helper functions give no results:

```
> dbListTables(con)
character(0)

> dbReadTable(con, "table_name")
Error in .oci.GetQuery(con, qry) : 
  ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Any ideas what may be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, they work for me if I specify a `schema` argument, i.e.

```
dbListTables(con, schema = "my_schema")
dbReadTable(con,"table_name",schema = "my_schema")
```

Additionally, it appears from reading `?dbListTables` that it has `all` and `full` arguments that control whether to look in all schemas, and whether to return the full schema name or just the table name.

Comment: Actually, I figured out that the schema is not necessary, but the table name should be in upper case in `dbReadTable` (but not in `dbGetQuery`). See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

After spending too much time trying to get to the bottom of this issue, I want to record the answer for posterity. Actually having the schema is not necessary in `dbReadTable`, but putting the table name in uppercase is. That is, the call should be

```
dbReadQuery(con, "TABLE_NAME")
```

Why?

To find out how `dbReadTable` is different from a `dbGetQuery` with a `select * from table` call, I dug for the source:

```
> showMethods("dbReadTable")
Function: dbReadTable (package DBI)
conn="OraConnection", name="character"
```

So it's an S4 method. We use `getMethod` with the above signature:

```
> getMethod("dbReadTable", signature = c(conn = "OraConnection", name = "character"))
Method Definition:

function (conn, name, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (conn, name, schema = NULL, row.names = NULL, 
        ...) 
    .oci.ReadTable(conn, name, schema = schema, row.names = row.names)
    .local(conn, name, ...)
}
<environment: namespace:ROracle>
```

`.oci.ReadTable` can be found [here](https://github.com/cran/ROracle/blob/master/R/oci.R), in the source of ROracle. All it does is check argument validity, call `dbGetQuery`, and set row names. The relevant part (calling `dbGetQuery`) is here:

```
# form name
if (is.null(schema))
  tab <- sprintf('"%s"', name)
else
  tab <- sprintf('"%s"."%s"', schema, name)

# read table
qry <- paste('select *',
               'from', tab)
res <- .oci.GetQuery(con, qry)
```

Note that if a schema isn't specified, the table name is used without the "schema." prefix. However, `sprintf` produces a quoted string for the table name, and [quoted table names are case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/oracle-what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do)! (`dbGetQuery` just passes an unquoted table name which can be lowercase.)

So that's why `dbGetQuery(con, "select count(*) from table_name")` works, as does `dbReadQuery(con, "TABLE_NAME")` but `dbReadQuery(con, "table_name")` doesn't.

Comment: Many thanks! This is exactly the issue I have!!