# Zend_Db_Table adds double quotes to table name when using PDO_OCI driver

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework, pdo

I'm trying to use Zend_Db_Table with PDO_OCI driver but when I try to use SELECT I get his exception:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 942 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/php-7.1.4/work/sapis-build/apache2/ext/pdo_oci/oci_statement.c:159), query was: SELECT "all_tables"."table_name" FROM "all_tables"
```

This is my code:

```
class Application_Model_Tables extends Coret_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'all_tables';

    public function getAll()
    {
        $select = $this->_db->select()
            ->from($this->_name, 'table_name');
        return $this->selectAll($select);
    }
}
```

and this is code that works:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$sql = 'SELECT table_name FROM all_tables';
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

So it is clear that there is problem with double quotes added to table name. Is this some PDO_OCI bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

I know what double quotes does because it works the same in PostgreSQL and I work with PostgreSQL for a long time. Problem was that I didn't know that "all_tables" is not the real name as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle) question. The real name for this table is ALL_TABLES and real name for the column is TABLE_NAME. So the correct answer is that I had wrong table and column names and this is not related to the suggested duplicate because answers from it would not help me at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: What exactly do quotation marks around the table name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/oracle-what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do)

Comment: As noted in the answer to the dupe; the double quotes cause case-sensitivity. You can probably just uppercase the `'all_tables'` and `'table_name'` strings to fix the problem.