# SQL Developer - 'table or view does not exist'

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-00942

I'm currently working on a project utilizing sequelize-oracle and oracledb, and I've created two functions that work okay, but the delete function has some issues.

This deletion ran fine in Postman.
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuXTq.png)

Then, when I went to SQL Developer and executed 'SELECT * FROM users' I realized that return me 'table or view does not exist', but the table 'users' have 29 users registered...

[SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZrRL.jpg)

I don't know why this doesn't work or why the table 'does not exist' if I have users into. The connection is fine, it isn't credentials errors because others functions are working fine in the same project.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the table was created using [case-sensitive identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do/563126#563126).  That means that you'd need to use case-sensitive identifiers every time you reference the table or one of the columns

```
select "id", "username", ...
  from "users"
```

Generally, using case-sensitive identifiers is frowned upon as an architectural choice.  It's generally pretty annoying to have to enclose every identifier in double quotes and to ensure that you're always using the same casing that was used to create the table & column.